# Find unique mobile device entries across different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, tracking

I want to trace the mobile user who are all enter into my app across different browser using JS  since I doesn't have native program knowlegde.(Java or Objecttive C).Is there any plugin available or any methods presents in javascript. I have done device fingerprinting. It gives details of a browser and cannot help to trace mobile entries across differ browser.

Comment: Try google analytics which will give you the required data of unique devices hitting your app, unless there is any requirement to use this information in our code anywhere.

Comment: @Sheetal — When did Google Analytics start tracking *devices*? It didn't last time I used it.

Comment: It does, under Users --> Devices and Network --> Devices. Even in the overview section you have new section called "Top Device Models" and a full report to be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't any way to track users across browsers (unless you issue usernames and passwords and take steps to prevent multiple accounts)

Comment: I asked about mobile user.i.e track unique device.My question may confused u.I just want to trace the unique device(user) entries.We can track by using device id or IDFA(ios 6).But don't know the way to implement it in java script(since i don't know java or other native language)

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Then how can I find my unique mobile device entries? Is there any other way other than scripting.

Comment: You still can't do it.